# Jquery Problem can anybody help me to solve my jquery code?

Tags: jquery

i have created a object called "customize" and add some properties

```
var Customize = {
currentTab: (""||"accountdetails"),
openonload: false,
firstview: false,//false,
init: function() {
    //$('.customize-tabs li a').click(Customize.showTab);
    $('#toggle_customize').click(function () {
        alert('yes');
        if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
            $('.cbm_control_closed').click(); // change this to Customize.close() when code is moved into that function
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
            Customize.open(Customize.currentTab);
            Customize.saveState();
        }
    });
    $('.cbm_control_closed').click(function() {
        $('#toggle_customize').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
        $('.customize-content').hide('fast');
        $('.customize-body').hide();
        $('.customize-pane').hide();
        $('#ui-tooltip-profile .button').click();
        // Hide save changes text
        Customize.Notifier.hide();
        // Get rid of heading pointer arrow
        $('.customize-tabs li').removeClass('active');
        Customize.saveState();
    });
    // set up Customize.Saver and field handlers
    Customize.initSavers();
    if (Customize.openonload) {
        //toggle customize modal
        $('#toggle_customize').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
        Customize.open(Customize.currentTab);
    }
    Customize.checkQueryActions();
},
open: function(which) {
    //legacy bug workaround
    //if (which != "services") { which = 'backgrounds'; }
    // show content
    $('.customize-body').show();
    // show nav
    $('.customize-content').show();
    // show tab
    Customize.showTab(which);
    Customize.showTooltips();
    UserProfile.offScreenFix();
},
close: function() {
    // TODO: move code from $('.cbm_control_closed').click to here
    // move $('.cbm_control_closed').click assignment to Customize.init
}};
$(document).ready(Customize.init);
```

now i want to call `$('#toggle_customize').click(function () {` this function so i have add this html code

```
<li id="toggle_customize"><a href="#"><span>Email Me</span></a></li>
```

but when i click on the "Email Me" there is no effect happen

but when i put this code outside the object variable its wokring

```
 $('#toggle_customize').click(function () {
    alert('yes');
    if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        $('.cbm_control_closed').click(); // change this to Customize.close() when code is moved into that function
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
        Customize.open(Customize.currentTab);
        Customize.saveState();
    }
});
```

Can any body help me to understand this code.

Thanks.

Comment: Well your href isn't poiting anywhere so that would explain why nothing happens.. No ?

Comment: yes but my code call "li" so it dosent affect to "a href".

Comment: please post your sample at http://jsfiddle.net so we can have html and js that you working on and track the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

Customize.init();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the anchor tag.  It's handling the click event before it gets to your `<li id="toggle_customize">`

Like so : `<li id="toggle_customize"><span>Email Me</span></li>`

If you're using the `<a>` just get get your underline or hover styling, you'll just have to do that some other way with css...

Comment: are you sure that you've run your Customize.init()?  and that it was run after the document was ready?

Comment: it looks like there's a lot more code to `Customize`.  could some other part have a bug?  are other parts of it working?  or is just this function broken?